# javascript regexp on keyup

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, keyup

i'm trying to make script which will replace all unwanted characters (from regexp) in input on keyup event. I tried everything but nothing works for me...

My code:

```
$('#form_accomodation_cell').on('keyup', 'input[name="accomodation_cell[]"]', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();
    var regex_cell = /^[0-9 \+]+$/g;

    if (!isNumeric(value, regex_cell))
    {
        var new_value = value.replace(regex_cell, '');
        alert(new_value);
    }

    function isNumeric(elem, regex_cell) {
        if(elem.match(regex_cell)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: _(...)but nothing works for me(...)_ what do you mean by that?

Comment: that alert show me new_value like value (with unwanted characters)...

Comment: So which are the _unwanted_ characters? What would you like to keep in the `new_value` if the `value` is `a123b12c`?

Comment: I want there only numbers, spaces and + character. Check my regexp - /^[0-9 \+]+$/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#form_accomodation_cell').on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var regex_cell = /[^[0-9 +]]*/gi;
    var new_value = value.replace(regex_cell, '');
    alert(new_value);
});
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F3ttb/1/) in action.

Comment: did you tried it? It's the same... Alert string is also with unwanted character (it doesn't replace it with '')...

Comment: and it's the same code like mine, you only changed event... (in your case it will not works on DOM elements)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to catch the event and finaly write this way !

```
function validateNumber(evt) {
var theEvent = evt || window.event;
var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
key = String.fromCharCode( key );
var regex = /^[0-9 \+]+$/g;
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
   theEvent.returnValue = false;
   if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
}
}
```